# UICollectionView Section headers & footers show wrong way - iOS

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, sectionheader

The problem is:
`SupplementaryView` has a `textLabel` on it, but the text appears at a wrong location while header and footer and textLabel just show right.

As you can see in the picture, only the first section header has a title, other header or footers text is out of sight(they are on the screen but you have to scroll down to see it).
I don't know how to solve it...

I setup my collectionview like following in `viewDidLoad` function:

```
func setupCollectionsView(){
    let width:CGFloat = self.view.frame.size.width/4
    let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 5
    flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 5
    flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSizeMake(width, width)
    flowLayout.headerReferenceSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 30)
    flowLayout.footerReferenceSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 30)
    flowLayout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.Vertical
    collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: flowLayout)
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.registerClass(FuncViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "collectionView")
    collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    collectionView.registerClass(SupplementaryView.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "headerView")
    collectionView.registerClass(SupplementaryView.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter, withReuseIdentifier: "footerView")
    self.view.addSubview(collectionView)
}
```

For each supplementaryview I write this:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    var view:SupplementaryView?
    var title:String = ""
    switch kind {
    case UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter:
        view = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(kind, withReuseIdentifier: "footerView", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? SupplementaryView
        view?.backgroundColor = UIColor ( red: 0.9879, green: 0.3225, blue: 0.4925, alpha: 1.0 )
        title = "Footer"
    default:
        view = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(kind, withReuseIdentifier: "headerView", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? SupplementaryView
        view?.backgroundColor = UIColor ( red: 0.6571, green: 1.0, blue: 0.8628, alpha: 1.0 )
        title = "Header"
    }
    switch indexPath.section {
    case 0:
        title = "First \(title)"
    default:
        title = "Second \(title)"
    }
    view?.setTitle(title)
    return view!
}
```

And my supplementary view implemented this way:

```
class SupplementaryView: UICollectionReusableView{
var titleLabel:UILabel!
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    titleLabel = UILabel(frame: frame)
    self.addSubview(titleLabel)
    let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(SupplementaryView.tap))
    self.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func setTitle(title:String){
    print("Label's frame is\(titleLabel.frame)")
    titleLabel.text = title
}

func tap(){
    print("\(titleLabel.text!) tapped")
}}
```

PS:I print the frame of each textlabel, they are just in right postion.
[image].

Answer (score 0):

Change you code as below, and to see if it works

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
     super.init(frame: frame)
    // There should be self.bounds
     titleLabel = UILabel(frame: self.bounds)
     self.addSubview(titleLabel)
     let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(SupplementaryView.tap))
     self.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
}
```

Comment: I just tried,and it worked fine!You saved my day! I've spent more than one day on it!